# IPMItool, bash script

Tags: bash, ipmi

i need to write a bash script that will go in the server to check the ip address of ipmi,

as i read that i can use

```
ipmitool lan print
```

i can write it inside server to show the ip address.

but i need to do this command on my local host and i tried to execute this command:

```
ipmitool lan print -H *servername* -U admin -P password
```

but i found this error

> Unable to establish LAN session

what is wrong with my command?

**Note:** i can access to the server using ssh without problem, but ipmitool doesnt work with ssh in same command line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your syntax is incorrect, since the right order should be:

```
ipmitool [options...] <command>
```

Moreover, in the parameter `-H ipmi_hostname`, the hostname here should be the domain name of IPMI interface IP address. It's quite odd to login via IPMI through its own IP to print out its IP(!), so I assume that you want to login via server's hostname. In this case, simply install ipmitool to server, then use SSH to run the command:

```
ssh hostname ipmitool lan print
```

If you still want to use ipmitool from another host to execute the IPMI command:

```
ipmitool -H ipmi_hostname -U ADMIN_USER -P password lan print
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thank u for ur help  

my fel was i wrote in the begining:

ssh hostname | ipmitool lan print

so we dont need to write pipe.

thanks again